# mysql_query returns nothing when called with special characters (The danish characters: æøå)

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I generate a mysql query from a form with a free text search field.
Something like:

`SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE 'something' LIKE '%SEARCH%'`

All this works fine and returns the valid rows when the search does not contain any special characters, like the danish characters ÆØÅ.

When these letters ARE used, the query returns no results, all though when i take the generated query string and plug it into phpMyAdmin i get exacly the result i want.

Thanks

Comment: ""..all though when i take the generated query string and plug it into phpMyAdmin i get exacly the result i want."" === Sorry can you explain this more detailed please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line of code in your connection file...

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $db);
```

it is better for you to encode your data to UTF-8 before you pass it into query...

Comment: mysql_set_charset does the trick :). Genious. I use json, so i use utf8_encode before passing the results. But it seems if i encode before executing the string, it won't work. Like mysql_query(utf8_encode("...")).

Comment: you must do it when your connection establish, that is why I asked you include it in your connection.php file instead of add into before the query string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Danish but Czech but I think there are the same (at least by UTF8 implementation) - you must keep in mind used encoding (original server script, data tables self and also your database connection handler).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an encoding problem, maybe phpMyAdmin is using a different client encoding than your other client. `SET NAMES 'encoding'` should just do what you need, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Also we can use PHP variable and convert it  before the select operation (supposing data base is ISOO-8859-2)   .

Example:

```
// word with special characters 
$search='kötészeti'; 
// conversion to ISO
$search=iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-2", $search);   
// create search condition
$condition="SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE 'something' LIKE '%$search%'"; 
// apply query
mysql_query($condition);
```